# Passing an array to javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, getjson

Is there a way that I can parse an array from a web service to javascript using $.get and not using a json object? I still didnt finish my code becaus I dont know if this kind of approach will work.

is this kind of code correct? or will it work?

```
var url = "receipt.php";

$.get(url, {receipt:receipt}, function(value) {     
    $(receipt.value).each(function(){

    });
});
```

the array to be returned is "value"

Comment: The client and server need to agree on a way to represent the array in the data. JSON is one way, XML is another. You have to specify.

Comment: `receipt.value` is a property of the object you sent as a parameter, not the response from the server.

Comment: Why don't you want to use JSON?

Comment: Can I pass the array as it self? without converting it to JSON or XML or any of that kind? just the array it self. I've experienced and done passing an array but the content of that is array is specified like this "return $value['0'];" but I'm wondering if I can pass all the data in value without specifying the data one by one like "return $value;"

Comment: I'm just a curious man and trying several things through several approach ^_^

Comment: you can't pass arrays directly between the server and client. The network requires everything to be serialized.